# Trying to understand dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to work out how to get PHP to tell me if a date is less than current date. The code I have written so far is;

```
<?php 

$test_date="08/02/2012";

$todays_date = date("d-m-Y");

if ($test_date < $todays_date) 
    {
    echo "Past";
    }
else 
    {
    echo "Future";
    }

?>
```

But the output says future? Any guidance on the best way to do this would be appreciated. - Thanks

Comment: What do you know about `string comparison`?

Comment: @u_mulder I know nothing about php string comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare dates with `strtotime`.
Otherwise, it compares `strings`, which is not what you want (unexpected result in this case).

Try this

```
$test_date = "08/02/2012";
$todays_date = date("d/m/Y");

if (strtotime($test_date) < strtotime($todays_date)) 
{
   echo "Past";
}
else 
{
   echo "Future";
}
```

Note you can also check for equality

Comment: I tried this, copied and pasted exactly but it still says future. It works OK if I used a hard coded todays_date but not as is.

Comment: Regarding on my example, your dates must be defined in d/m/Y format. Otherwise, it won't work as expected

Comment: Hi Justin, I understand that but the problem is happening with just the date("d/m/Y") part if I add a data manually it's fine.

Comment: Could you show me here what you tried ? What is working ? What is not working ?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new php file with nothing else, and then loaded the page in the browser and it says Future when it should say past.

Comment: Maybe this is because of timezone. Try using ISO format `Y-m-d` as follow: `$test_date = "2012-02-08"; $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");` and tell me if it's working that way

Comment: OK that works, so how I can I get it to accept the other format e.g. dd-mm-yy

Comment: Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y` format is assumed

Comment: But here in the UK we use slash /

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes, They are directly comparable and very useful.

```
$test_date= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', "08/02/2012");
$todays_date = new DateTime();

if($test_date < $todays_date){
    echo "Past";
} else {
    echo "Future";
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/kZnCX).